# SQL Select that inserts a new row based on a delimiter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following sample values:

```
ID VALUE
1 |856|421|
2 |123|795|7125|
3 |96412|85251|2245|
4 |4845|88422|9155|15154|
5 |1165|98742|
```

How can I do write a select statement where the result will be:

```
    ID Value    
    1 |856|
    1 |421|
    2 |123|
    2 |795|
    2 |7125|
    3 |96412|
    3 |85251|
    3 |2245|
    4 |4845|
    4 |88422|
    4 |9155|
    4 |15154|
    5 |1165|
    5 |98742|
```

The only constant is that each group of numbers are always included between | characters. Any ideas?

We need to preserve the pipes '|'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I borrowed this split string function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) on StackOverflow. Due your data is enclosed using `|` you must select only those values where data <> '' and finally add the delimiter again using CONCAT function.

> ```
> create function dbo.splitString(@input Varchar(max), @Splitter VarChar(99)) returns table as
> Return
>     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS Data 
>     FROM (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@input, @Splitter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
>     CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a); 
> GO
> ```

> ```
> Select id, concat('|', data, '|') value 
> from mytable x 
> cross apply dbo.splitString(x.value,'|') Y
> where data <> '';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | value  
> -: | :------
>  1 | |856|  
>  1 | |421|  
>  2 | |123|  
>  2 | |795|  
>  2 | |7125| 
>  3 | |96412|
>  3 | |85251|
>  3 | |2245| 
>  4 | |4845| 
>  4 | |88422|
>  4 | |9155| 
>  4 | |15154|
>  5 | |1165| 
>  5 | |98742|
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f0d74e8f4d09795e8e201f91791ec735)*

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with recursive SQL, although I can't say if that's a good idea. Data prep:

```
create table #my_table (
    ID INT,
    [VALUE] VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES (1, '|856|421|');
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES (2, '|123|795|7125|');
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES (3, '|96412|85251|2245|');
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES (4, '|4845|88422|9155|15154|');
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES (5, '|1165|98742|');
```

Recursive query:

```
WITH rec_CTE AS (
    SELECT
      ID
    , [VALUE]
    , SUBSTRING([VALUE], 2,  CHARINDEX('|', [VALUE], 2) - 2) substr
    , CHARINDEX('|', [VALUE], 2) + 1 last_pos
    , LEN([VALUE]) LEN_VALUE
    FROM #my_table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      mt.ID
    , rc.[VALUE]
    , SUBSTRING(rc.[VALUE], rc.last_pos , CHARINDEX('|', rc.[VALUE], rc.last_pos) - rc.last_pos) substr
    , CHARINDEX('|', rc.[VALUE], rc.last_pos) + 1 last_pos
    , rc.LEN_VALUE
    FROM #my_table mt
    INNER JOIN rec_CTE rc ON rc.ID = mt.ID
    WHERE rc.last_pos < rc.LEN_VALUE
)
SELECT ID, '|' + substr + '|'
FROM rec_CTE
ORDER BY ID, last_pos;
```

Results:

```
╔════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║  VALUE  ║
╠════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ |856|   ║
║  1 ║ |421|   ║
║  2 ║ |123|   ║
║  2 ║ |795|   ║
║  2 ║ |7125|  ║
║  3 ║ |96412| ║
║  3 ║ |85251| ║
║  3 ║ |2245|  ║
║  4 ║ |4845|  ║
║  4 ║ |88422| ║
║  4 ║ |9155|  ║
║  4 ║ |15154| ║
║  5 ║ |1165|  ║
║  5 ║ |98742| ║
╚════╩═════════╝
```